# How to store the empty data (null) in the oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Actually I need to insert all the data from the excel to the oracle database. In the below program, I am using object array to store all the different types of datatype used in the table.While doing so, I cannot able to store the empty value in the object array.

```
             public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {


   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    /* string ex_name = "";
     string ex_school = "";
     string ex_id = "";
     string ex_college = "";
     string ex_office = "";  */
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;

    //string str;
    int rCnt;
    int cCnt;
    int rw = 0;
    int cl = 0, i = 0;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Shanmugavel\Book1.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;





    rw = range.Rows.Count;
    cl = range.Columns.Count;

    object[] array1 = new object[100];
    int k = 0;
    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
        {


            array1[k] = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
            if (array1[k]==null)
            {
                array1[k] = null;
            }
            k++;

        }
        try
        {
            string oradb = "Provider=**;Data Source=**;User Id=**;Password=**;";

            string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO table_name
                     (SESSION_ID,TERRITORY_ID,SCANNER_SERIAL_NUM,RESPONDENT_ID,HOUSEHOLD_ID,QUESTIONAIRE_ID,SECTION_ID,QUESTION_ID,TEMPLATE_ID,DETAILS_ID,DATA,TIME_STAMP,INSERTED_DATE) 
                     VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(oradb);


            con.Open();


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[0];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[1];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p4", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[3];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p5", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[4];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p6", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[5];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p7", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[6];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p8", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[7];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p9", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[8];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p10", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[9];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p11", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[10];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p12", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[11];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p13", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[12];
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("p14", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = array1[13];

            k = 0;
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    if (i > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("Succesfull");
    }




    xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
    xlApp.Quit();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

}
```

}

It is showing error like **parameter does not have any default value**
If someone know, Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if (array1[k]==null)
                {
                    array1[k] = DBNull.Value;
                }
I tried the above one, It is showing error like  "non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"

Comment: `if (array1[k]==null)
            {
                array1[k] = null;
            }`  seems to be pointless.

Comment: Did you try like `.Value = array1[4] == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(array1[4]) ? DBNull.Value : array1[4];`

Comment: If I gave DBNull,value or DBNull.value.toString, It throws an error like " non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected "